# Access to the classType of generics in an autowired component

Tags: java, spring, generics, autowired

I have a component that is autowired in my controller,

Here is the code of my component :

```
@Component
public class Utils<T> {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private Class<T> mappedClass;

    public Utils(Class<T> mappedClass) { this.mappedClass = mappedClass; }

public T builder(String stringJson, T object) {
       /* doing staff ...*/
        return objectMapper.readValue(new TreeTraversingParser(jsonNode), mappedClass);
    }

}
```

my autowired component is using generics and when I m trying to access to the class type by passing it in the constructor. however i m getting this error :

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'Class' type found. Checks
>   autowiring problems in a bean class.

and when I launch my spring boot it says :

> Parameter 0 of constructor in ca.util.Utils required a bean of type
>   'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' in your
>   configuration.

How may I avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you try to instatiate Utils so we don't have all the information necessary.

Your first problem is that your @Component needs a constructor argument.
You can solve this if you instantiate your component using the ApplicationContext.getBean version that passes parameters.

Alternatively, You can supply the constructor argument using a @Qualifer annotation ( give the constructor argument a name, then supply it elsewhere )

Another Issue is that you have a raw generic type as your @Component. I've not seen that, so I'm not sure its possible. For @Component spring needs to create an instance of the concrete class.